# Loading native node addons from ES module

Tags: javascript, node.js, native

I have compiled a native `./addon.node` and it works fine with CommonJS `require`:

```js
const mod = require('./addon')
mod.add(1, 2)  // gets 3
```

But I can't figure out how to load that module in a `.mjs` file.

I've tried:

1. `import * as mod from './addon'`

Doesn't work, gets error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module ...
```

2. `import * as mod from './addon.node'`

Gets error:

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".node" for ...
```

3. `const mod = import('./addon')`

Gets error:

```
TypeError: mod.add is not a function
```

This looks interesting to me so I made a closer look by `console.log` it. I discovered that `import()` is async so I

4. `const mod = await import('./addon')`

Gets error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module ...
```

For importing `./addon.node`, gets the same error as 2.

I looked around and failed to find a workaround. Does anyone know if importing one is possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40541) issue, you cannot import a `.node` file into a `.mjs` file without the `--experimental-specifier-resolution = node` flag. According to [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40541#issuecomment-951096740) answer, you can create a `require` function.

```js
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

const nativeModule = require('./native.node');
```